# Creating .docx with OpenXML 2.5 causes corrupt file

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk, corruption

I am trying to create a document using OpenXML 2.5 SDK as detailed here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.document.aspx

My code looks identical to this, but when I try to open the created .docx file I get

> The file DocumentEx.docx cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents.

as an error in Microsoft Word

The problem is within the document.xml file which looks something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <w:document     xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
        <w:body>
            <a:p xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
                <a:r>
                    <a:t>Hello, Word!</a:t>
                </a:r>
            </a:p>
        </w:body>
    </w:document>
```

If I change the XML to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Hello, Word!</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

The file will open.

How do I get this to not save as corrupted? I must be missing something large to be having such an error from code I pulled from MSDN.

I am developing in Visual Studio 2010, .NET Framework v 4.6 SP1 and attempting to open these .docx files with Microsoft Word 2010.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems unlikely drawingml would have <p>, <r> and <t> structured the same as wordprocessingml. How do you get that namespace in a Word document, share code

Comment: You are correct. After further investigation this is my error. I was using DocumentFormat.OpenXML.Drawing as the namespace for the added Text instead of DocumentFormat.OpenXML.Wordprocessing. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 5):

My problem was that my Namespace for my added objects was incorrect.

I was using DocumentFormat.OpenXML.Drawing for my Text object instead of DocumentFormat.OpenXML.Wordprocessing. This was not rendering the text properly and causing my error.

Answer (score 0):

This may be for missing many header.
This below code does solves it. I have used office 2010

```
 <w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
    <w:body>
    <w:p>
    <w:r>
    <w:t>Hello , word</w:t>
    </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:sectPr>
    <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
    <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/>
    <w:cols w:space="708"/>
    <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
    </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
    </w:document>
```

Comment: It is because you might have missed many thing dependent .Check even your [content_types].xml

Comment: The thing is I'm trying to not have to manually manipulate the XML later. I want this process to be programmatic.